# last year as a timestamp?

Tags: php, timestamp

I found this snippet online which is supposed to give me the current year (2012) as a timestamp.

`$current_year = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, date('Y'));`

How can I get `$last_year`?

Comment: check this [Mktime() - Timestamp yesterday, last month,last year etc.).](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/1861-mktime-timestamp-yesterday-last-month-etc#last-year)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code.

```
$last_year = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, date('Y') - 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

In terms of speed, this is likeliest fastest answer:

`$last_year = time() - 31536000; // 31,536,000 seconds in a year`

Answer (score 1):

Subtract one from the year value:

```
$last_year = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, (date('Y') - 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
$startTime = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, date('Y')-1);     
$endTime = mktime(23, 59, 59, 12, 31, date('Y')-1);
```